# mongooseModel.find() doesn´t return the data from mongodb

Tags: javascript, typescript, mongodb, mongoose

I´m trying to fetch objects from my db. I already have another collection in my db, which I uploaded from my backend. I can import my mongoose model in another file and fetch the data by using `model.find()` without any problems.
Than I also manually uploaded a collection with the Name: SCVE_Files

[image]

where I uploaded 33 Objects (again - manually from hand).

It should have this model-schema:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const urlSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    lang: String,
    url: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  { _id: false }
);

const valueSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    lang: String,
    value: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  { _id: false }
);

const FileSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  data_type: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  data_version: Number,
  SCVE_data_meta: {
    ID: {
      type: String,
      unique: true,
      required: true,
    },
    ASSIGNER: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    DATE: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    STATE: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    SEVERITY: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  title: {
    title_data: [{ type: valueSchema, required: true }],
  },
  relationships: {
    relationships_data: [urlSchema],
  },
  description: {
    description_data: [valueSchema],
  },
  example: {
    example_data: [valueSchema],
  },
  recommendation: {
    recommendation_data: [valueSchema],
  },
  links: {
    links_data: [urlSchema],
  },
  _comment: String,
  search: {
    regex: {
      type: Boolean,
      required: true,
    },
    search_data: [
      {
        value: {
          type: String,
          required: true,
        },
      },
    ],
  },
});

export default mongoose.model('SCVE_File', FileSchema);
```

now I import the schema using `import SCVE_File from '../../../models/SCVE_File';`
and afterwards tried to log it to the console:

```
  // get all SCVE files from the database
  const scveFiles = await SCVE_File.find().catch(err => console.error(err));
  console.log(scveFiles);
```

However the console.log returns an empty array, while my other schema works out perfectly...
Could it be, that my schema definition is wrong? I am absolutely clueless what I could have done wrong...
Any ideas?
Also using `export default mongoose.model('SCVE_File', FileSchema);`
without the "s" in the end doesnt change anything, because mongoose adds it automatically doesnt it?

Comment: EDIT: I found out, that mongo db creates a new collection with the launch of my backend when connecting to mongodb. 
Instead of SCVE_Files the collection is called scve_files... 
How do I prevent mongodb from doing this and accept the already existing collection?

Answer (score 0):

From the mongoose [documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#collection), you can provide a collection name when defining a schema, if you don't want the auto-generated name, by providing an `options` object, as a second parameter:

**option: collection**

> Mongoose by default produces a collection name by
> passing the model name to the utils.toCollectionName method. This
> method pluralizes the name. Set this option if you need a different
> name for your collection.

You can try this, updating your schema definition like this:

```
const FileSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  data_type: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  data_version: Number,
  SCVE_data_meta: {
    ID: {
      type: String,
      unique: true,
      required: true,
    },
    ASSIGNER: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    DATE: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    STATE: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    SEVERITY: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  title: {
    title_data: [{ type: valueSchema, required: true }],
  },
  relationships: {
    relationships_data: [urlSchema],
  },
  description: {
    description_data: [valueSchema],
  },
  example: {
    example_data: [valueSchema],
  },
  recommendation: {
    recommendation_data: [valueSchema],
  },
  links: {
    links_data: [urlSchema],
  },
  _comment: String,
  search: {
    regex: {
      type: Boolean,
      required: true,
    },
    search_data: [
      {
        value: {
          type: String,
          required: true,
        },
      },
    ],
  },
},
{
  collection: 'SCVE_Files'
});
```